# is there a way to modify or send custom headers on grape?

Tags: ruby, goliath, grape-api

I'm using Goliath and Grape. On my goliath server it calls the grape api like so:

```
when '/posts' then FrameworksAPI::API.call(env)
```

On my grape api class, my method is as simple as this:

```
get '/:id' do
 Post.find(params[:id])
end
```

I'd like to modify the headers - specifically the 'Content-Length' but unsure how to.

Also i'd like to ask an additional question. How do i create callback/filters specifically before the method GET returns the result i'd like to modify the result.

Answer (score 7):

Grape has a `header` helper for a few versions now.

```
header 'Content-Length`, 42.to_s
```

For your second question on modifying the body, try using `after do ...` at API level.

Answer (score 0):

The return from your FrameworksAPI::API.call(env) method will be a triplet [status_code, headers, body]. So, instead of just returning that from your case you'd do something like:

```
when '/posts' then
  status, headers, body = FrameworksAPI::API.call(env)
  headers['whatever'] = blah
  [status, headers, body]
```

You can also change the body, just be careful as the body maybe an array.

There is also a Content-Length middleware that is provided by Goliath. Content-Length is loaded by default although if you set a custom Content-Length it will take precedence. Just be carefull that other middlewares like the formattings don't change the body after you set your content-length.